# Asynchronously search in a bunch of data and show responsive "Loading..." message

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've been asked to implement a `DataGridView` which show tons of data (100.000 rows for now) and has search function. The grid is implemented and the search works fine. While the CPU is searching the grid, I need a proper Loading...  message or picture. The only problem is that my UI is not responsive, it stops (hangs) until the search is finished.

I tried `gif` and it did not receive enough CPU time so it was like a dead image.
I tried a label with "Loading ..." message whose dots where being added on a timely fashion and had a dynamic look, but that was also hanging.

I am new with threading and asynchronous programming. I searched a lot but didn't get the whole concept. I even forked a dozen of sample codes but I still couldn't solve the puzzle.

Can someone give me a hint with this example so that I can understand the concept better and learn how to think async? Who (which thread) should do the search and who should do the paint?

Comment: From a user experience point of view, what possible use is a grid with 100000 rows? IMO it's an utterly useless requirement that should be queried with your superiors. Really. 1px of scrollbar movement will be around 100 rows. Pointless.

Comment: To add to "pointless" comment: it's also actively harmful, as users can tend to rely on big views like this to try to give themselves a kind of quick overview of the general nature of the data. It turns out that humans are really bad at this for anything above about 6000 records, and will instead end up grossly misleading themselves on what kinds of things are really contained in the grid.

Comment: I completely agree with you, the problem is that the man in charge wants whole the data in hand for various reasons which are not bad according to the state their network and distance has.

Answer (score 0):

The search functionality needs to be moved off the UI thread.  The UI thread is running the search, and cannot update the UI at the same time.

The best solution would be to use a `BackgroundWorker` to do the searching, and use the UI thread to show whatever waiting message you want.

Here's a link to a tutorial on MSDN on how to use `BackgroundWorker`s:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: No; use `await Task.Run()`.

Comment: The matter is that my search method takes all the CPU time and the background worker (which I had already tried) doesn't get enough time from CPU so the paint job fails.

Answer (score 0):

With .net 4.5, use async/await

```
private async void btnSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Searching";
        await Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); dataGridView1.Refresh();/*search here*/ });
        label1.Text = "Finished"; ;
    }
```

With .net 4, using Task with Invoking for main thread

```
private  void btnSearchClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Searching";
        Task.Run(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);               
            this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                dataGridView1.Refresh();/*search here*/
                label1.Text = "Finished";
            }));                
        });
        ;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what if i want the message to be interactive? I mean consider dots adding to the message each 500 ms until there are 3 dots, then the dots disappear and this repeats. In this scenario I want to rapidly refresh the UI.

Comment: Create your own control, in that control has 2 Method, Start() and Stop(), in method Start() using Timer to adding/removing dot for each 500ms, Stop() will stop Timer. Finally in Search function call yourControl.Start() and Stop()